# Python 3.x: ImportError: cannot import name 'scandir'

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de usar el módulo scandir y me da el error:  **ImportError: cannot import name 'scandir'**.
No lo entiendo, se supone que la versión que estoy usando, la  3.4.4 ya tiene implementado este módulo.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sería conveniente que agregaras tu código para ver como realizas el `import` y poder ayudarte mejor. ¿Quieres usar [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) o el módulo [`scandir`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir)? Porque en el primer caso si que es estandar pero en el segundo caso se trata de un módulo externo que debes instalar.

Comment: @FJSevilla: para empezar, mi código es de lo más simple: `from os import scandir`

Comment: Me pregunto si hay alguna manera de saber si 'scandir' lo tengo en mi librería de os y en el caso de no estarlo cómo se puede instalar.

Comment: @FJSevilla: Gracias, no sabía la diferencia. Quiero usar el que es estándar, el `os.scandir()`

Comment: He agregado una respuesta, culpa mia por no leer y pasar por encima lo de `3.4.4...` `os.scandir()` se agregó en `Python 3.5`, de hecho es una de sus mejoras destacadas, por lo que no existe para  `Python 3.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.scandir()` es una característica agregada en la versión 3.5 de Python, no está disponible para la 3.4 como puedes ver en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).

Una posible solución es usar el módulo externo [`scandir`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) instalandolo via `pip`. Para ello abres la terminal (CMD de Windows) e ingresas:

```
pip install scandir
```

si todo va bien y se instala correctamente lo importas así:

```
from scandir import scandir
```

Otra opción es usar [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) o [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) dependiendo de tus necesidades y que si están disponibles en `Python 3.4`